# Can the types of parameters in template functions be inferred?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, auto, c++-concepts

I'm writing some template functions in C++, but I'm not sure if it's possible to define a template function that infers the types of its parameters.

I tried to define a template with inferred parameter types, but this example won't compile:

```
template <auto>   
auto print_stuff(auto x, auto y) 
{ 
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```

It works when I give a unique name to each parameter type, but this seems somewhat redundant:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

template <class Redundant_1,class Redundant_2>   
auto print_stuff(Redundant_1 x, Redundant_2 y) 
{ 
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{ 
    print_stuff(3,"Hello!");
    return 0; 
}
```

Is it possible to define a template with inferred parameter types instead of giving each type a unique name?

Comment: `template <auto> auto print_stuff(auto x, auto y)` – would you now require the two `auto`s to be of same type (you only have one template parameter!) or to differ as in your example?

Comment: @Aconcagua I expected each `auto` to be a different type, but `template <auto,auto>...` doesn't work either.

Comment: That could work at all if you have the same number of template parameters and function arguments. If numbers differ, compiler can't ever be able to know which auto in the function argument list matches which auto in the template parameter list. Committee might have considered requiring both parameter lists having the same size being a too strong limitation to be worth to allow the whole stuff. Be it the true reason or not, I personally join it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dispense with the template-header and names for the parameter-types if your compiler supports concepts, which isn't generally enabled even if asking for experimental C++2a mode.
On gcc for example, it must be separately enabled with `-fconcepts`.

See [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4150e6ae391cb01).

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

auto print_stuff(auto x, auto y) 
{ 
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{ 
    print_stuff(3,"Hello!");
    return 0; 
}
```

As an aside, avoid `std::endl` and use `std::flush` in the rare cases you cannot avoid costly manual flushing. Also, `return 0;` is implicit for `main()`.

Comment: `return 0; is implicit for main` – maybe, but many consider it bad style not doing so...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the C++2a spec... is there a reason `auto` is the return type for `print_stuff` rather than `void`?

Comment: @Aconcagua Imho, for a [mcve] adding anything optional is bad style. And considering he used `std::endl` everywhere...

Comment: @andand No, I just stayed close to the source. Since C++14, `auto` can be used for return-type-deduction, but here it deduces `void`.

Comment: (a) just Concepts (b) it is part of C++2a.

Comment: Hm... You didn't add the return inside main, it was there already, and the last sentence is optional... So would it be bad style now? ;)

Comment: @Barry Gcc insisting on separate invitation confused me.

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sure, they just don't have full concepts support yet. I just mean that this feature will be in C++20.

Comment: Hm, C++ is getting more and more python like with that. I personally don't feel comfortable with...